# handle digital fingerprint in PHP

Tags: php

Is there any interface or php library that can autenticate users by their fingerprint.

- Any software that php can use to do
  this?
- Any hardware that can be used for this?

Comment: Handle in what sense, please elaborate.

Comment: and what's wrong with user-name\password?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP is *almost certainly* the wrong solution to this problem.  PHP has no easy way to interface with hardware unless you're prepared to write an extension in a low-level programming language.  (It's hard to capture fingerprints without, say, the hardware to scan them in.)

You best bet is going to be asking the manufacturer of your fingerprint scanner of choice about their recommended way to interface with it.  If you don't *have* the hardware, you're probably out of luck here on SO.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what you mean by handprint; but, I've worked with biometric scanners in the past that have an API that shares enough data to fake it.

Answer (score -1):

Java would probably be the most efficient language to use a fingerprint scanner, aside PHP could be used to retrieve the data *somehow*.

Comment: Do you know any example?, or any scanner?